# Adding ID tag to Header tags <h1><h2> in a stand alone PHP page

Tags: php

This code (see below) adds IDs to header tags, which can then be used as anchors.It basically converts the H1/H2... text into lower case, replaces spaces with '-' and puts it into the ID tag.

However, this code is a filter for Wordpress only.

**Question :** 
How can I modify it to make it work on a normal stand alone PHP page, where the content is being displayed with a `echo $content;`

**Did I try to make this work?** 
With my limited programming language, I tried to make this code work. Couldn't do it.

**Did I do research ?** 
I found lots of code snippets / plugins that work with WP, but none for standalone PHP pages.

**What is the objective ?**
Take the `echo $content;` , run it though this code to sanitize H1/H2...text (lower case, spaces replaced with '-') and put it in the 'ID' tag of the same H1/H2 etc. Which can then be used as anchors.

Will sincerely appreciate any help from the experts.

```
//Author URI: http://stephanis.info

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_ids_to_header_tags' );
function add_ids_to_header_tags( $content ) {

    $pattern = '#(?P<full_tag><(?P<tag_name>h\d)(?P<tag_extra>[^>]*)>(?P<tag_contents>[^<]*)</h\d>)#i';
    if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
        $find = array();
        $replace = array();
        foreach( $matches as $match ) {
            if ( strlen( $match['tag_extra'] ) && false !== stripos( $match['tag_extra'], 'id=' ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $find[]    = $match['full_tag'];
            $id        = sanitize_title( $match['tag_contents'] );
            $id_attr   = sprintf( ' id="%s"', $id );
            $replace[] = sprintf( '<%1$s%2$s%3$s>%4$s</%1$s>', $match['tag_name'], $match['tag_extra'], $id_attr, $match['tag_contents']);
        }
        $content = str_replace( $find, $replace, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Note : I am not affiliated in anyway with the plugin mentioned above. I am simply trying to use the code / similar code for standalone PHP pages.

---

@kry The code snipped works in the manner you have explained. But when I try to use it like below, it doesn't do anything.

**Current file :**

```
<?php

$original_text = file_get_contents($url);

$content = $parser->text($original_text);

echo $content;
```

**What I am trying to achieve :**

```
<?php

$original_text = file_get_contents($url);

$content = $parser->text($original_text);

// Here I want to take the $content and add the text in the h1, h2... tags as 'ID'
// for the same tags after changing to lower case & replacing spaces with '-'

function add_ids_to_header_tags( $content ) {

    $pattern = '#(?P<full_tag><(?P<tag_name>h\d)(?P<tag_extra>[^>]*)>(?P<tag_contents>[^<]*)</h\d>)#i';
    if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
        $find = array();
        $replace = array();
        foreach( $matches as $match ) {
            if ( strlen( $match['tag_extra'] ) && false !== stripos( $match['tag_extra'], 'id=' ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $find[]    = $match['full_tag'];
            $id        = sanitize_title( $match['tag_contents'] );
            $id_attr   = sprintf( ' id="%s"', $id );
            $replace[] = sprintf( '<%1$s%2$s%3$s>%4$s</%1$s>', $match['tag_name'], $match['tag_extra'], $id_attr, $match['tag_contents']);
        }
        $content = str_replace( $find, $replace, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

function sanitize_title($title) {
    return str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
}

print add_ids_to_header_tags( $content );
```

Unfortunately the function is not adding anything to the h1, h2... tags. It is just returning the same content as was before.

The format of the h1, h2 tags in the source content looks like this :

```
<h1>DataRun<a name="API_Quickdata"></a></h1>
<h2>Data Request Parameters<a name="API_Quickdata_RequestParameters"></a></h2>
```

What I want them to look like :

```
<h1 id="datarun">DataRun<a name="API_Quickdata"></a></h1>
<h2 id="data-request-parameters">Data Request Parameters<a name="API_Quickdata_RequestParameters"></a></h2>
```

Comment: does it have to be done with PHP? It's quite simple ( if I understood correctly ) to do this in javascript

Comment: Why don`t you read the html file using file_get_contents(), and echo return parameter for new html file ?

Comment: @RamRaider , BRjava - Added more explanation to the original question. It doesn't have to be done in PHP. It can be Javascript also. Since the PHP snippet to make this happen was also available, I have been trying to use it. Either approach will work for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned briefly this task is relatively straightforward using Javascript so I put together a quick demo. To see the final result you need to `inspect` the html using the developer tools ( F12 on Google Chrome etc )

To accomplish the same thing in PHP I guess you would need to use `Output Buffering` and then run the search/replace just before flushing the buffer to the browser ~ thus putting more load on the server whereas using javascript leaves it to the client.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>search DOM for h1,h2 (only) and modify ID</title>
        <style>
            body, body *{
                box-sizing:border-box;
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
                font-size:1rem;
            }
            p{width:90%;float:none;font-style:italic;margin:0.25rem auto;text-indent:-2rem;}
            p:first-letter{font-size:1.5rem;color:gray;border:1px solid silver;border-radius:0.1rem;background:whitesmoke;padding:0.1rem;}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                /* 
                    capture a reference to all h1 & h2 elements and iterate through using `forEach`
                    As `document.querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist it is not always possible in all
                    browsers to natively use `forEach` hence using `Array.prototype.slice.call` to 
                    generate as an array...
                */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2') ).forEach(function(header){
                    /* the replacement character */
                    let chr='-';

                    /* simple regex to find space or underscore characters */
                    let pttn=new RegExp(/[\s_]/gi);

                    /* modified regex */
                    let pttn=new RegExp(/[\s_\:\/]/gi);

                    /* convert text of h1,h2 nodes to lower case and replace characters */
                    let text=header.textContent.toLowerCase().replace( pttn, chr ).replace( /\-{2,}/gi, chr );

                    /* 
                        if the h1,h2 already has an id - capture the id and manipulate using previous method.
                        multiple spaces are replaced as a single character ( hence chained `replace` cmds )
                    */
                    let existing=header.hasAttribute('id') ? header.getAttribute('id').replace( pttn, chr ).replace( /\-{2,}/gi, chr ) : false;

                    /*
                        create new ID
                    */
                    let id=existing ? [existing,text].join( chr ) : text;

                    /* Apply ID to element */
                    header.setAttribute( 'id', id );
                })
            },{ capture:false, once:false, passive:false } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DataRun<a name="API_Quickdata"></a></h1>
        <h2>Data Request Parameters<a name="API_Quickdata_RequestParameters"></a></h2>

        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Hocus Pocus <a href='#'>Hyperlink to nowhere</a></h1>
        <p>Chrono ix no nullam viderer eleifend, dictas invenire delicatissimi in has. Aeque voluptatibus te eam, sit falli inermis corrumpit ea, timeam deserunt assentior no his. Tale vero impetus in has, oblique copiosae ea nam, cum ex nusquam similique. Sea in elit disputationi. Ei natum porro feugait eos, no has quas corpora indoctum.</p>
        <p>Septus pro no natum doctus honestatis. Usu ei cibo tantas, id habeo accumsan antiopam duo, ex vis esse suscipiantur consectetuer. In sed magna persequeris. Ea vel graece percipit consequat.</p>
        <p>Sit aperiam expetendis disputationi vel cu, has ei blandit conclusionemque. Sit illum inciderint cu, ex tempor detraxit pericula mei. Legere aliquam at eum, ea partem fierent gloriatur cum. Habeo apeirian sed ne. Iudico adipisci et vim, in civibus salutatus vis, pro et nisl fuisset.</p>

        <h2 id='slippery_orange_potus'>Nusquam delicatissimi - with an existing ID</h2>
        <p>Regis pro in meis iriure utroque, inimicus liberavisse suscipiantur ius id, mea habemus interpretaris at. Ea vix consul graeco praesent, no usu tacimates referrentur interpretaris. Stet animal consequuntur eos ea, eum suavitate temporibus voluptatibus at. Eu dictas nominati intellegat quo, et per semper omnesque. Fabulas invidunt id his, possit discere cu quo.</p>
        <p>Ocurreret et vehicula in, neque pretium nonummy urna orci a, mauris dui ut id tortor ullamcorper feugiat, consectetuer amet nulla vel ex, congue vel urna justo sit mus et. Wisi quam morbi convallis urna massa elementum. Sed dui. Pellentesque sed eget mollis, donec at vel wisi, tincidunt magna sequi tincidunt. Scelerisque et commodo.</p>

        <h1>Iudico adipisci et vim</h1>
        <p>ConstituamNe dolorem hendrerit definiebas pri. Nusquam delicatissimi duo no, ut noster tamquam honestatis vim. Justo ocurreret necessitatibus cu mea, in eirmod definiebas mea. Ex dolorem definiebas vituperatoribus quo, utinam vocent aliquam ut est, in pro nullam impedit suscipiantur. Eam ea porro ancillae. Eius numquam epicurei sed ei, mucius platonem accommodare mei eu, percipit accusata ad usu.</p>
        <p>Kino pro in patrioque sadipscing, in debet elaboraret constituam qui, per ne regione eruditi. Sit quis definiebas vituperata ut, mel veri adolescens te. Nam ea modus graece voluptua, vel in dicta veniam. Usu cu oratio accusamus interpretaris.</p>       
        <p>Sodales Pulvinar pede libero libero consequat. In in enim magnis odio dui, pretium iaculis erat sed condimentum, felis proin id. Amet viverra mauris lacus nunc justo. Felis viverra fusce et neque volutpat consectetuer. Lectus lacinia. Dui arcu justo neque vivamus fusce. Diam nulla ornare sodales ut vitae per, ipsum eu id lorem sed.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example of modifications made]

Comment: Beautiful! It works perfectly. Considering that the website will be hosted on a basic shared hosting account, the Javascript approach is the ideal solution. Thank you !

Comment: can I bother you a wee bit more ? The Javascript works perfectly, just need a small tweak. The titles occasionally have a ":" or a "/" character in them. Can these two characters be stripped out ?

Comment: for example `<h1>Files under the /accounts Directory</h1>` to be used as `<h1 id="files-under-the-accounts-directory">` - i.e. the : & the / characters to be replaced with nothing.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

(Wanted to make a comment, but it has become too long...)

Anyway, it currently seems to work on the test servers without WP. Like the code is:

```
$content = '<h1>kontent with whitespace</h1><h2>kontent2 without whitespaces</h2>';
function add_ids_to_header_tags( $content ) {

    $pattern = '#(?P<full_tag><(?P<tag_name>h\d)(?P<tag_extra>[^>]*)>(?P<tag_contents>[^<]*)</h\d>)#i';
    if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
        $find = array();
        $replace = array();
        foreach( $matches as $match ) {
            if ( strlen( $match['tag_extra'] ) && false !== stripos( $match['tag_extra'], 'id=' ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $find[]    = $match['full_tag'];
            $id        = sanitize_title( $match['tag_contents'] );
            $id_attr   = sprintf( ' id="%s"', $id );
            $replace[] = sprintf( '<%1$s%2$s%3$s>%4$s</%1$s>', $match['tag_name'], $match['tag_extra'], $id_attr, $match['tag_contents']);
        }
        $content = str_replace( $find, $replace, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

function sanitize_title($title) {
    return str_replace(" ", "-", $title);
}

print add_ids_to_header_tags( $content );
```

As you can see, I added a replace at the end, and cut the WP function at the start. The end result is:

```
<h1 id="kontent-with-whitespace">kontent with whitespace</h1><h2 id="kontent2-without-whitespaces">kontent2 without whitespaces</h2>
```

which means, it currently works, I think you want this to happen. Please note, that if two tags have the same content, they will also have the same name. If this is not what you want, please explain what is the final state you want to achieve.

Comment: I have added some more explanation to the question itself. You are right, if two tags have the same content, they will also have the same 'ID'; which is ok.What I am trying to achieve is : 

The h1, h2 tags in the source content look like this:

`<h1>DataRun<a name="API_Quickdata"></a></h1>
<h2>Data Request Parameters<a name="API_Quickdata_RequestParameters"></a></h2>`

What I want them to look like:

`<h1 id="datarun">DataRun<a name="API_Quickdata"></a></h1>
<h2 id="data-request-parameters">Data Request Parameters<a name="API_Quickdata_RequestParameters"></a></h2>`

Comment: Your preg is no good anymore, never going into the if, which requires further investigation.

Comment: I'm crap at regex. Doesn't this mean match anything in content as long as it doesn't have '<'? `(?P<tag_contents>[^<]*)`

Comment: :) I guess the php approach is not ideal. As suggested by Ramraider, the Javascript approach works great.